# Why in my ios app on Paypal sandbox the buyer can cancel the payment?

Tags: ios, cordova, paypal, sandbox

I'm working in a phonegap app where i've used the phonegap paypal ios plugin (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK-PhoneGap) to accept payments inside my app.

The thing is that that plugin uses the new Paypal iOS SDK (which I like), and i've set a sandbox environment through the paypal developer portal (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps) to test the payments.

The problem i'm facing is that when I do a payment, the buyer CAN cancel the payment, which is something that i dont understand why, and obviously i don't want because i need to send physical goods, and i would not like to send a product to a customer that cancels his payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payment is unclaimed as the recipient doesn’t exist so the buyer would be able to cancel the payment if the recipient doesn’t register with that email address to claim it. If nothing happens (buyer doesn’t cancel and recipient doesn’t register) then the payment is returned to the buyer after 30 days.

Comment: Thank you again for everything